# Java files are system independent?

Tags: java

Many people used to say that Java is a system independent programming language; the same .class file can be run (interepted) in any OS using the appropriate OS JVM.
My question - is the .java file itself also system independent? i.e. is a .java file that was written (and can be compiled correctly) in one OS, can be compiled correctly in another OS? If not, do you have any example to show this?

Thanks!

Comment: **>> If not, do you have any example to show this?**: Not all .java sources can be compiled for the Android OS, despite both being ".java".  What matters isn't the file extension, but what Java API/ VM the source was written for.

Comment: a .java file using features from java 1.6 won't compile using a java 1.4 compiler

Comment: @carnold, the question wasn't Java source, it was .java file.  Dalvik (Android VM) uses .java files.

Comment: I meant Java source, not .java :)

Comment: @jedwards Dalvik don't use *.class files

Answer (score 1):

As long as `.java` file follows the API syntax and correct versions, it can be compiled on any operating system irrespective of where it is coded.

Comment: I think the source file encoding (UTF-8 or different) my cause a plattform-dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes. Long answer, yeeeeeeesss.

One exception, as noted by `jedwards` in the comments on your question, would include Android since the libraries available in the Android SDK are different than the JDK distributed by Sun. This is more of a JVM-specific distinction, but since Android is technically an OS, it counts. This can also extend to Java ME and Java EE, but this is still more JDK/library dependent, not OS dependent.

Another exception may be if you use classes under proprietary packages, such as those in the `sun.*` or `com.sun.*` packages. Then it will be *JVM* dependent, but it still won't be OS dependent as long as you're using the right version of Sun's JVM.

So really, strictly speaking, as long as the JDK version that you're using is available for your OS and any native libraries you're using (think JNI) are available for your OS, the .java files will compile with no issues on your OS. Now whether or not it runs is another issue entirely.

Sidenote: we used Mac OS X 10.4+, Ubuntu 8.04+, and Windows XP/Server 2003+ for software development all at the same time at my last job, and it never caused any problems outside of the occasional it doesn't *run*, but never any issues with compiling.

Answer (score 0):

the java compiler is ported to mac/win/linux and will generate a valid and *maybe* equal binary - cause it can have timestamps inside.
and the .class format is universal so that any VM port will be able to read them correctly

Answer (score 0):

The answer is IT DEPENDS:

The Sourcecode is NOT system independent, if you make mistakes.

one exmple:

You write a Sourcefile with a system dependent charakter encoding. If you transfer that file to another system, where that chrackter encoding does not exist, your file may be unable to compile. This is more an compiler issue.

another example:

If you have a customized JVM with system dependent addons, a program using this classes my become unusble at other systems. This is more a classpth issue.

If you use correct encodins and don't import plattform dependent packges like com.sun.* or com.apple.* the *.java and *.class are independent.